# Matching IDs in two different tables

Tags: php

I have two tables; NEWS and CATEGORIES. In the NEWS table, there is CatID field which matches with CatID table in the categories. I get the categoryID with the following code but I want to the category name of the news, not the ID. How can I pull it from the categories table?

```
<?php 

 $SQL =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM News WHERE Active = 1 ORDER BY DateEntered DESC");

   while ( $Result = mysql_fetch_array($SQL)) {
 $CatID[] = $Result[CatID];
 $NewsName[] = $Result[NewsName];
 $NewsShortDesc[] = $Result[NewsShortDesc];
 }
?>

                <div class="toparticle">
                    <span class="section"><?=$CatID[0] ?> </span>
                    <span class="headline"><?=$NewsName[0] ?></span>
                    <p><?=$NewsShortDesc[0] ?></p>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some text, can you please update and add the missing details of what you get and what you want to do?

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking is JOIN (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your SQL query to include an inner join to get the name.  To illustrate, I'm going to make the assumption that the category name column in the 'CATEGORIES' table is called 'CatName.'  You can use this query:

```
SELECT n.*, c.CatName FROM News n
INNER JOIN Categories c ON n.CatID = c.CatID
WHERE Active = 1
ORDER BY DateEntered ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

By what I've understood, maybe you want to do:

`SELECT name FROM CATEGORIES as c, NEWS as n WHERE c.CatID = n.CatID AND n.CatID = 123`

I'm a bit rusty in SQL, I think it's something like this.

From what I've understood from your question, you want to do something like this.

Comment: The next answer seems better :)

Answer (score 0):

In the following I create 2 table for news and categories :

Table News

**id| cat_id | title**

1   |   1    | Test

Table Categories

**id  | name**

1   | Horror

u can select name of category use OUTER JOIN like this

```
SELECT news.*, categories.name AS category_name FROM news 
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id= news.cat_id;
```

if u want to know more about this [outer join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html)